# Unable to show first viewcontroller passed values to second viewcontroller in swift

Tags: swift, mkmapview, pushviewcontroller

My second viewcontroller contains mkmapview.. all the time map must to show current location address values in textfields only but when i send values from firstviewcontroller then only it should show firstviewcontroller's address values in its textfields

Initially second viewcontroller textfields showing current location values(like: city, street, etc)

now i am sending first viewcontroller address to secondviewcontroller.. but here secondviewcontroller always showing current location values only.. why?

**firstvc code: sending address to 2ndvc:**

```
 func btnEditTapped(cell: EditAddressTableViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = self.addeditTableview.indexPath(for: cell){
        print("edit button address index \(indexPath.row)")
          let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileAddressViewController") as! ProfileAddressViewController
        
        var addrLo = addressArray[indexPath.row]

        print("in edit total mode address \(addrLo.pincode)")// in console in edit total mode address Optional("530013")
        viewController.editPincode = addrLo.pincode
        viewController.editStree = addrLo.streetName
        viewController.editColony = addrLo.city
        
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**my secondvc code:** here i am unable to show firstvc's values why?

```
class ProfileAddressViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, DataEnteredDelegate {


var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   
var addressModel : ProfileModelUserAddress?
var editAddArray = [String]()

var addressArray = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var titleNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var pincodeField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var cityField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var streetField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var editPincode: String?
var editStree: String?
var editColony: String?
var isEdit = Bool()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    if isEdit {
        titleNameLabel.text = "Edit Address"
        
        pincodeField.text = editPincode
        streetField.text = editStree
        colonyField.text = editColony
        
    }
}
   
@IBAction func backBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let _: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }

    let userLocation :CLLocation = locations.last! as CLLocation
    latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    logitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
        if (error != nil){
            print("error in reverseGeocode")
        }
        let placemark = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]

        if placemark.count>0{
            let placemark = placemarks![0]
            print(placemark.locality!)
            print(placemark.administrativeArea!)
            print(placemark.country!)
            let placemarkDictonary: NSDictionary=placemark.addressDictionary as! NSDictionary
            self.pincodeField.text=placemarkDictonary["ZIP"] as? String
            self.cityField.text=placemarkDictonary["City"] as? String
            self.streetField.text=placemarkDictonary["Street"] as? String
        }
    }

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: logitude!)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    let myAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocation.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    myAnnotation.title = "Current location"
    mapView.addAnnotation(myAnnotation)
}
}
```

please let me know, how to show firstvc's passed values in 2nd vc

Comment: add this line in your firstVC 'viewController. isEdit = true'

Comment: @BijenderSinghShekhawat, if i give 'viewController. isEdit = true' title is changing but pincodeField, streetField, colonyField not changing... why

Comment: I don't know... You should debug step-by-step to see what really going on

Comment: @BijenderSinghShekhawat,  thank you got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you set value for the `isEdit` somewhere else?. If not, the initial value for the `isEdit` will be `false` since you are using the initializer of `Bool` which returns `false` by default, therefore, your code that initiates values for your text fields inside the `if` statement will never get run. That's why you don't see the values you've passed from the first VC.

Comment: if i give `'viewController. isEdit = true'` title is changing but pincodeField, streetField, colonyField not changing... why?